# flutter detect pointer device kind

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, stylus-pen

I want to draw on screen only when the stylus pen device is used and should not detect any finger input in flutter [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJ6Or.png)

I am using this package https://pub.dev/packages/painter.
please help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Listener` class.

```
handleTouchEvent(event){

    if (event.kind == PointerDeviceKind.stylus){
      ////
    }

};

Listener(
      onPointerDown:handleTouchEvent ,
      onPointerUp:handleTouchEvent,
      onPointerMove:handleTouchEvent
      child: child,
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).